# Discard changes not working properly when IDE is Open

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, webstorm, git-revert

There was a problem on all the computers of the team about a month ago.Discard changes(git) not working properly when IDE is open.We have different IDE in the team( web storm, visual studio code).When Ide is open i cannot do revert change,but when i close ide -all work fine.I work with smart git and get following message when i discard change

```
Discard: unable to create file src/app/pipes/transform-email/transform-email.pipe.ts: Permission denied
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is the `src/app/pipes/transform-email/transform-email.pipe.ts` file open in vscode?

Comment: yes.but It work fine before

Comment: Try closing that file. Git doesn't always complain when files inside the repo are open, but when it does, it looks like that.

Comment: Are you using WSL?